How to avoid session creation in cookies when going to STATELESS in spring 6
I am using spring security with spring 6(XML based) and tomcat.
Previously i was using session but now i am moving to JWT. I already set it create-session="stateless"  in spring-security.xml but it is still creating session in cookies.
After login if removed JSESSIONID form cookie and sending only JWT token in the request and hit a request, it is not logging out but getting 403 forbidden.
So how to disable session completely from application if going to stateless.
This is spring-security.xml config
<security:http create-session="stateless" security-context-explicit-save="true" use-authorization-manager="false" use-expressions="true" auto-config="false"  authentication-manager-ref="authenticationManagerWithMultipleProviders" security-context-repository-ref="nullSecurityContextRepository">

You don't. The fact that your security is stateless doesn't mean the rest of your application won't create a session. If you are using JSP it will create a session by default for instance.

Yes, my application is using JSP. So how to remove session completely? I want to remove completely because same server handling REST calls also, this is reason i do not want to dependent on session.

The fact that there is a session cookie doesn't mean you rely on sessions.

But if i delete session cookie and hitting url, then getting 403. It is not logging out because authentication is done by token sends in request but getting 403 in response for requested url.

You cannot logout with tokens, as you will always re-authenticate with the token. A 403 means forbidden which is an authorization issue not an authentication issue. If you wouldn't be authenticated you would get a 401.

I added below code to web.xml
<session-config>         <session-timeout>1</session-timeout>         <cookie-config>             <max-age>0</max-age>         </cookie-config>  </session-config>
and removed HttpSessionEventPublisher from web.xml
Now session is not coming in cookies. By this way I achieved what i want i.e. to remove session from cookie. But I am not sure it is correct way of doing or not because server still generating session, I am only expiring session immediately to remove from cookie.
is this correct way of doing this? if not what other thing can i do?
